# RightClick "Assign shortcuts" doesnt work in Edit-mode?

Tags: python, edit-mode, shortcut, customization

I am using my own custom menu,
and i discovered that i can assign shortcuts to "my operator"
but i cant assign shortcut to the same thing while in editmode.
in editmode the shortcuts cant be assigned and disappear if assigned in object mode.
Its because of the way i scripted?
All the operators works fine if i "click" them in any mode.

The standard menu of blender works fine in edit mode too.
For exampe
While in editmode-faces , i can assign a shortcut to the Right-click "pokefaces"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a lot of blender depend on the "context"
Being in Editmode and "Assign shortcut" will not , create a shortcut for edit mode.
Instead the default Behavior is create a shortcut for the category expressed in the bl_idname.

So having named the operator  object.myactions will create a shortcut for the "object category "
If i used the name                      wm.myactions  the shortcut will be placed in "window"
The shortcut for object will be ignored while in editmode,

So, create your operators using the category you want that to be placed
or
Create manually the shortcuts
(for example going in preference keymap , window and add your operator like object.move_x
it will work even with the object. because mapped in window)